# login.live.com with python and mechanize?

Tags: python, mechanize-python

I need to automatically login with python and mechanize on login.live.com.
The problem is,that I can't find any browser.forms(), but there should be some, since I checked the HTML code:

My code:

```
import urllib2
import lxml
from mechanize import Browser

br=Browser()

#Simulate user
br.set_handle_robots( False )
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'GoogleChrome')]

#open site
url = "https://login.live.com/"

rep = br.open(url)

for frm in br.forms(): 
    print frm
```

There should be a form named 'f1' on 'login.live.com'. Is it possible, that this part is generated dynamically?

Nero

Answer (score 1):

The answer from https://login.live.com has empty body. Everything is done through javascript onload.

To see yourself you can (on Mac and Linux at least):

```
wget https://login.live.com/
```

Or in your code:

```
import urllib2

from mechanize import Browser

br=Browser()

#Simulate user
br.set_handle_robots( False )
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'GoogleChrome')]

#open site
url = "https://login.live.com/"

rep = br.open(url)

print rep.read()
```

It may be hard/impossible to get these forms without executing javascript, but to do so I think you will have to leave python. EDIT: Or maybe you don't have to (see other answers).

If you have no need to actually analyze the site respones and just want to do some simple things there you can just make your requests without caring too much about responses (you still have http status codes which may be enough to see if your requests succeded).

I guess there is also actual API. I'm not familiar with MS products and don't know exactly what you are trying to do, so I cannot point to anything specific.

Answer (score 1):

As sbarzowski pointed out you need to execute the javascript on the site.
But you don't need to leave python for that. In fact you could automate Qt webkit.

Example (python3, tested on linux):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from urllib.request import urlopen

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

SHOWBROWSER = True
LOGIN = 'name@example.com'
PASS = 'foo'

class WebPage(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WebPage, self).__init__(parent)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl('http://login.live.com'))

    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, msg, lineNumber, sourceID):
        print("JsConsole(%s:%d): %s" % (sourceID, lineNumber, msg))

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        frame = self.mainFrame()
        url = frame.requestedUrl().toString()
        print(url)
        if url == 'http://login.live.com/':
            frame.evaluateJavaScript(self.get_jquery())
            frame.evaluateJavaScript(
                '''
                $('input[name="login"]').val('{login}')
                $('input[name="passwd"]').val('{password}')
                $('input[type="submit"]').click()
                '''.format(login=LOGIN, password=PASS)
            )
        if 'auth/complete-signin' in url:
            print('finished login')
            if not SHOWBROWSER:
                QApplication.quit()

    def get_jquery(self):
        response = urlopen('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js')
        return response.read().decode('utf-8')


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.view = QWebView(self)
        self.view.setPage(WebPage())

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setMargin(0)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)


def headless():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QWebView()
    view.setPage(WebPage())
    app.exec_()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if SHOWBROWSER:
        main()
    else:
        headless()
```